# How to read and convert a table from pdf to xml/html?

Tags: c#, html, ocr

Here is a [pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt96anv61dddup6/Y.pdf?dl=0)

How can I convert the table (thorugh ocr or something like that) to a html table like(and save it to a txt file)

```
<table frame="box">
<colgroup>
<col span="5"/>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Y+z</td>
<td>Avg.</td>
<td>X2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Abc</td>
<td rowspan="2">15.236</td>
<td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Yko</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ink</td>
<td>Pol</td>
<td>IUk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ll adl</td>
<td rowspan="2">6369</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qwwe</td>
<td rowspan="2">330</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tyu</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The table might have rowspan and colspan as well..
Thanks in advance..
This is what I did

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ocrText = GetTextFromPDF(@"C:\Temp\Y.pdf");
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Y.txt",ocrText);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static string GetTextFromPDF(string path)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }
    }

    return text.ToString();
}
```

But it read all the contents of the pdf file and I don't know how to further process this to get the desired result.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, what options do you have, as the guidelines state, "do your own research first". Please provide us with some information about your attempts

Comment: @H.J.Meijer I've updated the question with what I tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `SautinSoft.PdfFocus.dll` for this kind of things, below is a little sample code to convert pdf to xml:

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.XmlOptions.ConvertNonTabularDataToSpreadsheet = false;
f.OpenPdf(@"D:\XY.pdf");
f.ToXml(@"D:\XY.xml");
```

Best of luck:)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a question technically very hard.

The PDF format is a specific format for printing systems, or better: the binary format that represents a PDF is a format we say so typographic.

In general, it is difficult to parse a PDF format to obtain data that can be processed.

This is due to the fact that the internal data of a PDF would be seen in a confused way by a text processor, in fact they are so compiled for special applications, such as PDF viewers.

There are several tools that try to extract data from PDFs, but in general they are not 100% reliable because they are based on image recognition.

So, if you need to extract data, using PDF is not a good thing. It would be perfect if you could get the source document from which the PDF was generated. For example a markdown or an Excel sheet.

---

If you really insist and you settle for data that could be erratic, you can try [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=from+pdf+to+html&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).